# UISwitch not reaction

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is probably simple. My UISwitch from my xib is connected to an IBOutlet "switch".

however when i create the viewController, i want to check if a variable is YES/NO, and the switch should be the correct value.

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
if(variable ==YES){
   [vc.switch setOn:YES];
}else{
    [vc.switch setOn:NO];
}
```

however its always unchecked. What could i be doing wrong? i´ve double checked the connection to the IBOutlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created ViewController, but not presented it. So loadView was never called and yours .switch is nil.
try this:

```
ViewController *vc = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentViewController:vc
                   animated:YES
                 completion:^(){
    vc.switch.on = variable;
}];
```

Comment: What if he doesn't want to present it? What if the vc is supposed to be pushed.

Comment: loadView is called inside pushViewController, so you are able to set UISwitch value after pushing view controller. I can't add comment in your's answer, but vc.switch.on = variable is equals to [vc.switch setOn:variable]

Answer (score 3):

You aren't calling the correct method; `UISwitch` doesnt' have a `setOn` method. it has an `on` property and a `senOn:animated:` method.

either:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
vc.switch.on = variable
```

or:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc.switch setOn:variable animated:YES];
```

Note, you are already checking against a BOOL, I've shown how to do it without the needless check.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common problem new developers have. Actually i had the same problem once. at that time i don't know the reason of happening this. i think now i am clear about such problems.

Let me give you some tips.

1. You should never access any `UIView` controls before presenting or pushing viewcontroller. you can access the UIView controls after presenting/pushing.
2. You can achieve this by setting the boolean value also. Create `deafultSwitchStatus` boolean property because its a boolean type this value will remain memory before `viewDidLoad`. and you can assign this status to your `UISwitch` object in `viewDidLoad.`

In short. `UIView` controls are not created/loaded before `viewDidLoad` method and `viewDidLoad` is called after preseting/pushing any controller. it means your controls are nil if you are accessing before presenting/pushing. those controls will not have any effect of your code because it will be overwritten.

Hope i explained right :)